# Identify & Remove "Duplicate" PPT files that are not 100% the same

Tags: c#, python, powershell, cmd, powerpoint

As part of the Discovery process for an upcoming project, I am trying to find a way of taking a representative sample of the PPT files on our network. So far, I have collected & organized all of the PPT files that we have, however I've realized that there is an overwhelming volume of documents, such that I need to find a way to reduce it down. To this end, I was thinking that it'd be helpful to delete all "duplicate" files.

Our company does not have any sort of version control system for files on our network. As such, users often create copies of files in order to make small minor changes. This has led to a high volume of "duplicate" files with no real naming convention, etc. Ideally, I'd be able to make a best-guess as to which files are "duplicates" and keep the most recent version. Since I just need a representative sample, I do not need to be 100% accurate regarding the save/delete decision and it's also ok if I lose a chunk of the files due to (there are currently 135K files, and I expect to end up with 3-5K). I am not sure how to go about this, as tools like http://www.easyduplicatefinder.com/ seem to look for truly identical documents, as opposed to a more nuanced difference.

Here are a couple of additional details:

- File names do not follow any standard convention
- I think it's fair to assume that many of the PPT properties would remain unchanged across versions
- Versions of files are always located in the same folder, however other PPT files may also exist in the same folder
- I'm open to addressing this problem in any of the following languages/technologies: C#, VB, Ruby, Python, IronPython, PowerShell

Comment: First order of business is to evaluate existing powerpoint diff software to see if it works for you. Powerpoint is highly scriptable and you could use [Presentation.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff746389%28v=office.15%29.aspx) to convert to something that it more "diffable". Perhaps converting to rtf and then using your favorite "differ" from there.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney - As I mentioned in my post, I've looked into a number of diff solutions, but most of them can't do what I'm looking for. That being said, you're suggestion of moving the data OUT of PPT and into a more "diffable" format is a great one. I'll look into that route. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it like:

- extract all visible text strings from each .ppt file
- dump the strings into text files, one per .ppt
- run `diff` across all pairs of text files (in the same directory?) to get min edit distance
- run the resulting distance matrix through a clustering algorithm

Comment: Hugh's suggestion of extracting text strings. It will be more effective if along the way you ungroup any ungroupable pictures, OLE object, charts, smartart and the like; otherwise, the text they contain will be invisible to most text extraction methods.  Naturally, you'd do this on a temporary copy of the file rather than the original.